# How do I add an instance of a class without the constructor's parameters?

Tags: java, constructor, instance-variables

I'm trying to create a fantasy football draft program. The first step I'm having a hard time is reading the data into a List properly. I want to scan the data, line by line. I created a loop that sets each role name, then goes on to add all the people who have that role until "-----" shows up on a line. Then that role is added to the list of Roles. I believe my loop is all correct for that, however, I do not know how to work my Person constructor correctly so that it contains a rank, name, and origin that I can't achieve with the setData method in the Person class. I'm still a beginner at programming, and I want to know if I'm missing something.

## Data File

Leader

1   Superman    DC

2   Captain America Marvel

3   Professor X Marvel

4   The Shoveler    Mystery Men

Brawn

1   Hulk    Marvel

2   Wolverine   Marvel

3   The Thing   Marvel

4   Beast   Marvel

5   Thor    Marvel

6   Mr. Furious Mystery Men

7   Mr. Incredible  Pixar

...and so on

## Main Class

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner; 
import java.io.*; 
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class FantasyTeamDraft {

/**
 * Joseph Simmons
 * CPS 181
 * February 6, 2013
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
    Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
    
    System.out.println("Enter the name and location of the file wanted for the draft: "); 
    File draftData = new File (scan.next());
    Scanner scanData = new Scanner(draftData); 
    
    List <Role> listOfRoles = new ArrayList <Role> (); 
    while (scanData.hasNext()) {
        String line = scanData.nextLine(); 
        if (!isInteger (line)) {
            Role role = new Role (); 
            role.setRoleName(line); 
            String personLine = scanData.nextLine(); 
            while (isInteger(personLine)){
                Person person = new Person(); 
                person.setData(personLine);
                role.addPerson(person); 
            }
            listOfRoles.add(role); 
    } 
        }
     
    
    
    
    
}

public static boolean isInteger (String line) {
    try {
        Integer.parseInt(line.split("\t") [0]); 
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        return false; 
    }
    return true; 
}
```

}

## Person class

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Person {

private int rank; 
private String name; 
private String origin;

public Person () {
    
}
public Person (int rank, String name, String origin) {
    this.rank = rank; 
    this.name = name; 
    this.origin = origin; 
}

public void setData (String line) {
    String [] array = line.split("\t"); 
    this.rank = Integer.parseInt(array [0]); 
    this.name = array [1]; 
    this.origin = array [2]; 
}
```

}

## Role Class

```
    import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Role {

private String roleName = ""; 
private List <Person> listOfPeople;

public Role (String roleName) {
    this.roleName = roleName;  
}

public void setRoleName (String line) {
    this.roleName = line; 
}

public String getRoleName() {
    return roleName; 
}

public void addPerson (Person person) {
    this.listOfPeople.add(person);  
}
```

}

Comment: Are you getting any specific error?

Answer (score 0):

In your code I see

```
 while (isInteger(personLine)){
            Person person = new Person(); 
            person.setData(personLine);
            role.addPerson(person); 
        }
```

This will be infinite loop if `isInteger(personLine)` evaluates to true. Perhaps it should be if instead of while, or you need to modify `personLine` in each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

You have two constructors

> public Person () {

```
public Person (int rank, String name, String origin) {
this.rank = rank; 
this.name = name; 
this.origin = origin; 
}
```

If I understand your question correctly, in order to set value for rank, name and origin, you would want to call the second constructor. But in your loop here

```
while (isInteger(personLine)){
            Person person = new Person(); 
            person.setData(personLine);
            role.addPerson(person); 
        }
```

You are invoking `new Person()` here, try changing it to invoke the other constructor.

Comment: I understand that I need to do that, but I can't get "int rank, String name, and String origin" before using the method .setData. How do I go about htis?

Comment: Once you invoke the default constructor, all values are going to assigned to a default value, and since in the code ur invoking setData right after constructor, it is calling the setData method.

Comment: So what do I do after I call the setData method?

Answer (score 0):

Make a constructor that accepts a string, just like setData, then call your setData method in that constructor, sending it the string. This way you keep setData and your constructor is basically setData().

If you want to absolutely keep the constructor as it is, you'll have to split up the string in the main